# Cryptic clue I can't solve

Tags: cryptic-clues

I'm new to cryptics but I managed to complete an entire puzzle from The Nation except for one clue where I'm stuck:

> "A strip said to be possibly what was popular in living rooms once (10)" .

And IF I answered all of the other clues correctly, then the pattern for the answer to this one is as follows:

> _s_i_i_t_a

Probably simple for you experts out there but it has me stumped!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a pretty obscure word (one that I hadn't heard before):

> "[Aspidistra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspidistra)"

is a genus of plant often used as a houseplant.

The clue should be parsed with

> "to be possibly" as an anagram indicator, and "a strip said" as the fodder to be anagrammed (with the rest being a definition).

Comment: That. Was. Fast. +1

Comment: Wow!  I'm impressed!  And although I have heard the word I would have never guessed it "was popular in living rooms once"....  Thanks much!

Comment: @lhartney and Deusovi - this word would be much better known in Britain - it's still fairly common to see them as houseplants here! Plus George Orwell wrote [this novel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_the_Aspidistra_Flying), which I suspect might be its only appearance in a book title! :)

Comment: I don't know if this is its only appearance in a song title, but here's the wonderful Gracie Fields singing her song The Biggest Aspidistra In the World. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHN-ZQzkJJU#t=28

Comment: Sorry, there is a problem with Wikipedia.